# imapX illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, .net, filepath, illegal-characters, imapx

PLEASE NOTE, I have found a work around which actually works out better for me. That is to use the byte stream and decode rather than save at all. Therefore answers are non-essential but I would still be interested in any comments people have.

Having trouble with illegal characters in path. I have tried many different versions of the same thing, surely it's just a path I need, and I'm fairly sure I know what one looks like! Can someone suggest what I may be doing wrong?

I am using http://hellowebapps.com/products/imapx/

Connection and everything else is okay!

Code:

```
            foreach (Message m in _imapClient.Folders["Football"].Messages)
            {
                m.Process();
                List<Attachment> attachment = m.Attachments;

                foreach (var a in attachment)
                {
                    a.SaveFile(@"C:\FileDrop\hello.csv");
                    //a.SaveFile(@"C:\FileDrop\");
                }
            }
```

Stack Trace:

> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.    at
>   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)    at
>   System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access)    at ImapX.Attachment.SaveFile(String downloadLocation)

Comment: Not even this works! a.SaveFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way it seems to get around this is to get the string from the attachment data directly - using [Encoding.GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) with [Convert.FromBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)

```
return _encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(contentStream));
```

Then just save the file as normal: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

[Path.GetFullPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Comment: Hi insomnium, sorry for not noticing your answer sooner. I had a go with this with no luck. I really need to ask for the source code as the error message makes no sense, I've seen a lot of paths and this one does not look illegal! I thought perhaps it required only a directory path - but tried that to no avail too.